# I see this line in a make file with extension .mk what does this mean

Tags: makefile

I am trying to add a library to the build so that i can call the API of the i2c_client to write my own wrapper around core drivers. For similar case in Uart i found that they have included a line like this

#===== LIBS - a space-separated list of library items to be included in the link.
LIBS+= slog2
LIBS+=^uart_client

What is the meaning of the second line here (LIBS+=^uart_client)?

Did not find any info regarding this syntax

Comment: It doesn't have any special meaning. It just appends `^uart_client` to the end of `LIBS` (after a space).